# What is the size of uninitialized struct vs uninitialized class in c#?

Tags: c#, class, struct, reference

I have not been able to find the answer to this although it might be obvious.

My question is two-fold.

Imagine I have a member variable which is not initialized until needed.  I know that if this member variable is of a class type, the size of the member variable will be the size of an int when it is initialized as it will just reference an object instance.

Question 1 is: What is the size of an uninitialized member variable here?  I am thinking it is most likely the same (the size of an int) and is some kind of null reference but I wanted to ask since I'm not finding it for sure.

Question 2 is: What is the size of this member variable if it is a struct type?  What is the size if uninitialized?  My guess is that the size is sizeof('struct_type') either way but I would appreciate confirmation.

Thanks!

I am wondering if an example might help to clarify for me

```
public struct StructChild
{
    public int One;
    public int Two;
    public int Three;
    public int Four;
    public int Five;
}

public class StructParent
{
    public StructChild Child;
}

public class ClassChild
{
    public int One;
    public int Two;
    public int Three;
    public int Four;
    public int Five;
}

public class ClassParent
{
    public ClassChild Child;
}
```

In this example, would StructParent be roughly 5 times the size of ClassParent?

Comment: Fields of a class or struct are always initialized, the CLR provides the guarantee that they are default(T).  Assigning a value does not change size.  The size of a struct is not the plain sum of the size of its members, bytes may be left unused between members and at the end to ensure fields are properly aligned in memory.  Alignment is a memory model implementation detail and depends on the target processor.  None of this ought to affect what you do in code.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for taking the time to help me. I understand what you are saying but in a rough sense would a "ClassParent" instance be smaller than a "StructParent" one. I am asking out of both curiosity and the intent to use the flyweight pattern. I am thinking that I would not want to use a struct as the flyweight for the reason I stated in the example but was hoping for confirmation.

Comment: There is no *real* distinction, ClassParent still needs to allocate the storage for ClassChild to be practical.  Objects of a reference type (class) have overhead, every object has an object header.  8 bytes in 32-bit mode, 16 in 64-bit mode.  They do have [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)] unlike a struct which might reduce object size when it can reshuffle the members.  Not here, no gaps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know that if this member variable is of a class type, the size of the member variable will be the size of an int when it is initialized as it will just reference an object instance.

No you do not know that because it is false.

References are 32 bits in a 32 bit process and 64 bits in a 64 bit process. **That's why we call them 64 bit processes**.

A reference is only the size of a 32 bit int in a 32 bit process.

> What is the size of an uninitialized member variable here?

First of all, there's no such thing as an *uninitialized member variable*. All member variables are initialized to their default values by the memory allocator. There are *unassigned* member variables, but there are no *uninitialized* member variables in C#. An unassigned member variable has the value it was initialized with: it's default value.

Second, the size of a variable does not change when it is assigned. Member variables of reference type take up as much storage as one reference whether they are assigned or not.

> What is the size of this member variable if it is a struct type?

That is implementation defined. It depends on details such as how the structure members are packed, and whether there are any layout attributes.

> My guess is that the size is sizeof('struct_type')

`sizeof(T)` for user-defined-type T only works in *unsafe code*, and only when the struct is all "unmanaged" types, like integers, pointer types, and so on.

But when it does work, yes, you can rely on it to tell you how big a thing is in memory.

Note that the marshaller's SizeOf tells you how big a thing is *when it is being copied across a marshalling boundary*, not how big it is in memory.

> In this example, would StructParent be roughly 5 times the size of ClassParent?

No. You're forgetting that all object that are instances of reference type (including boxed value types) have an object header. The object header is the size of two references.

On a 32 bit machine we would expect an instance of StructParent to take up 20 bytes for its fields, and 8 bytes for its header, for a total of 28. An instance of ClassParent takes up 8 bytes for the header and 4 bytes for the member variable for a total of 12, which is not one fifth of 28.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it is very detailed and informative and it corrected my silly mistakes in my question!  This is all the information I was looking for and more.

Comment: Sorry for commenting again but rereading your answer I am slightly curious about "In your specific example you can be pretty confident that StructParent and StructChild are the same size." and "On a 32 bit machine we would expect an instance of StructParent to take up 20 bytes."  Can you explain that a bit more?  If I am reading your answer correctly, shouldn't StructParent also have an 8 byte header (not that 12 is one fifth of 28 either)?

Comment: @Mason: If we boxed it then yes, there would be an 8 byte header. But a normal, everyday variable of value type is just big enough to contain the fields of the value type without additional information. Do you see why the CLR does not need the header information for an unboxed struct?

Comment: Yes I think I do, but in my original example "StructParent" is a class (sorry if my naming was confusing)

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Then yes, StructParent, as a class, has an 8 byte header on all its instances.